# Building Android from Source -Case sensitive file system

Tags: android, linux, ubuntu, virtualbox

I'm trying to build the android source on an Ubuntu virtual machine with virtualbox.  When I compile, I get an error stating that the source must be compiled on a case sensitive file system.  Linux is obviously case sensitive, but I wonder if it is detecting my windows disk.  Does anybody have any experience with this sort of thing?  Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends what you mean by "detecting your Windows disk".

Ubuntu does not distinguish between a native hard disk and an image file that resides on a Windows file system. In both cases, case sensitivity depends only on the file system visible to Ubuntu. So, if you create an ext3/4, btrfs,... partition, it will be case-sensitive.

However, if you share a directory between Windows and the guest operating system, case-sensitivity is inherited from the host file system. If that file system is case-insensitive, Ubuntu will see a case-insensitive file system. I guess, that's the problem in your case? As solution, I'd move the build process to some non-shared location, i.e. some path in your Ubuntu-local file system.

Comment: Thanks for confirming.  I ended up creating a dedicated machine